# ElasticSearch was very slow until DELETE index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with 240 indices with index freq. by 10 documents per second.

The cluster goes very slow until i execute DELETE request, after that the index process and search requests continue with good throughput.

So what DELETE request did?

Comment: what are you deleting? all indices or just ab big one?

Comment: Yes a big one (many indices). I've deleted wildcard

Comment: @RichieK ping reply

Comment: Well, if you delete all your data, your cluster will be faster afterwards. Generally that's the point of having a time based index — once you reach the data retention you are targeting you can simply delete the indices that are older.

Comment: @xeraa i didnt delete all the data, i just figure it out what delete command did underhood

Comment: You'll need to figure out what is the resource limit you are hitting (I'd guess memory). Once you have found out what it is, you can start planning how to fix it: Maybe you have too many shards for your setup, maybe you just need to add resources,...